Installation of omicverse failed — it still indicates that scikit-misc is missing after successful installation
I encountered an installation failure while trying to install the omicverse module. Using conda/mamba, I followed the recommended steps from the installation guide at https://omicverse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation_guild/. However, when I proceeded to install omicverse, the following error occurred:
(omicverse) F:\>mamba install omicverse -c conda-forge

Looking for: ['omicverse']

conda-forge/win-64                                          Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
pkgs/main/win-64                                              No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/msys2/win-64                                             No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/msys2/noarch                                             No change
pkgs/r/win-64                                                 No change

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.10.*


Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ omicverse is not installable because it requires
   └─ scikit-misc >=0.1 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).

(omicverse) F:\>pip install scikit-misc
Collecting scikit-misc
  Downloading scikit_misc-0.4.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.23.5 in c:\users\cann\miniforge-pypy3\envs\omicverse\lib\site-packages (from scikit-misc) (1.26.4)
Downloading scikit_misc-0.4.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (10.0 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 10.0/10.0 MB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: scikit-misc
Successfully installed scikit-misc-0.4.0

(omicverse) F:\>mamba install omicverse -c conda-forge

Looking for: ['omicverse']

conda-forge/win-64                                          Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/win-64                                                 No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/main/win-64                                              No change
pkgs/msys2/noarch                                             No change
pkgs/msys2/win-64                                             No change

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.10.*


Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ omicverse is not installable because it requires
   └─ scikit-misc >=0.1 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).


I have checked that my CUDA version is compatible, and the environment is using Python 3.10 as recommended by the installation guide (the same issue occurs with Python 3.12).
What should I do next to successfully install omicverse?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Generally bioinformatics tools are not developed for Windows. Even though this tool claims support for native Windows, I'd question whether this is thoroughly tested. If you must use Windows, then I would strongly recommend getting comfortable with WSL2 and recommend try installing that way instead (also in the documentation).
However, one can also enable Conda to recognize pip-installed packages as sufficient by setting the pip_interop_enabled configuration option. This is an experimental feature, so I recommend understanding what it does (see this thread). One could turn it on for the environment:
## ensure the environment is activated
conda activate omicverse
conda config --env set pip_interop_enabled true
conda install -c conda-forge omicverse

Alternatively, you could just temporarily enable it to see if it helps:
CONDA_PIP_INTEROP_ENABLED=1 conda install -n omicverse -c conda-forge omicverse

